# Vuejs installed or not?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am a beginner in Vuejs.I want to develop an application with laravel and Vuejs.I have follow the step of installing laravel and Vuejs and execute this `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel demo "5.8.*"` command.I verify to check that Vuejs is installed or not by adding the extension of Vuejs in google chrome and it showing Vuejs is installed.But when i execute the command `vue --version` in the putty by connecting server through SSH then it shows error that "vue command not found".Why?

May be this question is not proper to ask but i am very confusing that actually Vuejs is installed or not.And is the Vuejs files structure is same or different?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check package.json the existence of vue

Comment: Yes over there "vue" version is written.But when i execute the command then it throws error as i mention in the question.I thought if it is installed then it must be able to show using command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing and compiling vue into a laravel project is different than using the vue cli.

In Laravel, Vue is included in the assets registry in the `package.json` file.

`npm` uses this file to pull in assets then allows you to build them. It pulls them in with `npm install`

Note: you need [node.js](https://docs.npmjs.com/downloading-and-installing-node-js-and-npm) installed on your system.

The build commands you can see at the top of the `package.json`. They usually are:

`npm run dev`, `npm run prod`, and `npm run watch`.

Here is the documentation on getting started with Laravel and Vue:

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/frontend

Comment: I thought that as vuejs is mention in "package.json" file then it must execute all the commands of vuejs.

Comment: Laravel uses webpack to compile.

Comment: Ok and what if node_modules in missing but npm is installed?

Comment: just run `npm install` and that will pull those.